# AJAX xhr.responseText returns the whole html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

First I echo my datas in the php, I tried it with very simple ones, like:

```
echo json_encode(array("one" => "something"));
```

Then I try to catch it inside my ajax calling I previously wrote for that php (and is working):

```
succcess: function (xhr,data) {
        var something = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(something);
            }
```

But I get a syntax error for JSON.parse() everytime:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

so I just logged out the `xhr.responseText` which the "data" is, and it returns the **whole html** of the page.

If I log out the **xhr** (which should contain the html I think), I get this:

> XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0,
>   withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload…}

I would like to get back only the json encoded data, not the whole html.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

---

Edit: 
The problem was that this php generated html content before the php statements, which was equal of echo statements, so the ajax couldn't distinguish it from the data I wanted to send. I made another php file to do this task and now it works properly.

Comment: show us the whole of your php page where that `echo json_encode...` command is. Are you outputting other things on that page as well?

Comment: It is a quite long php. I output html elements like select-options and input fields. For some I use echo too actually

Comment: Ok. So you should move the code which creates the JSON response into a separate file maybe, and call that file specifically from your AJAX request. Otherwise PHP will just run the whole script and return everything  that is output by that script. Or, alternatively, at least use an if/else to run different parts of the script depending on what the requested action is

Comment: They are already separated with if-statements. I use the ajax's get method to run the statement, then I want to send some information back to the ajax via php, and I only use this one echo in that if statement. And the ajax returns the whole html, not only that part of it what my if statement generates.

Comment: *"They are already separated with if-statements."* Then maybe your conditions are incorrect..

Comment: What I am trying to do is only a bonus feature in a working php (and ajax). And actually an important feature, but I did not create new else statements or something. So I doubt it could be the problem, but w/e

Comment: So you didn't create new if-statements? Maybe you need a new one for your new output, to separate it from the other outputs? Or maybe it's dropping out of the if-block and outputting some stuff elsewhere that outputs despite that? Without seeing all of the code (or at least the relevant parts) we can't help any further I don't think.

Comment: I still don't want to copy here the full code, because one hand it most of it has nothing to do with my problem, in the other hand it's the property of the company I work for. It is a part of a CMS which has a lot of problems actually. The jquery it uses is outdated (which can be a problem of the ajax too), and something is wrong even with the php settings. The module I'm working on is a php file which creates a .csv and and .xls with from the requested statistics, and there is a problem with the downloading through php, because it only outputs the content of the file in the html,

Comment: doesn't allow to download it, only when I use a helper php outside of the CMS. I already asked about this problem here but the topic was marked as duplicated and the linked answer didn't work, because something is wrong with the settings not with my code. So as alternative solution I communicate with the downloadhelper php through ajax, and I want to send the ajax the name of the generated file, and that's where the things go wrong, because I can't just echo it, because xhr.responseText returns the whole html what the php creates on that page

Comment: I tried alternatively that when the php script is executed, it generates a hidden html input which contains the filename as a value, and I could read it through ajax, but the input field is established only if I send the xhr into the html in the ajax's success function, which generates further problems that are even harder to solve in this case

Comment: One simple question: What are the very very very first characters of your php file? Please post at least the first 10 ... The answer to this question will give us valuable hints ... otherwise we won't be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

Add to the php response a header with Content-type

```
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo json_encode(array("one" => "something"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve this problem

Comment: Try now to remove JSON.parse, now you have JSON response, you can do console.log(data);